# Emacs Predictive Mode does not work for LaTeX documents

Tags: emacs

After installing the Predictive Mode package for Emacs 23.3 on Windows 7, it will not load the LaTeX libraries when I run the Predictive-Mode function. I get the following message:

```
Warning (emacs): Predictive major-mode setup function predictive-setup-latex failed; latex-mode support disabled
```

Predictive mode is functional for non-Latex documents. Has anyone run into this before? How do I get predictive mode to work for Latex documents, which is why I wanted to install it anyway?

The path to the predictive folder and the latex folder is `C:\Program files (x86)\emacs\.emacs.d\predictive\latex`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: While emacs questions aren't exactly off topic here, they tend to go unanswered. You might be better off asking your question on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com)

Answer (score 2):

Predictive Mode must be compiled. Please, check the answer on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/326431/why-is-emacs-predictive-mode-not-working-for-latex-documents/328812#328812)